# How can I use a json file if all elements are in one array?

Tags: json, p5.js

I'm trying to learn to import JSON files into p5.js.

I'm using this list of English words: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json

I already know how to import things when the entries are organized into respective categories. It seems every entry is in the same array, though. How can I import individual entries?

Comment: The linked file is a map of strings not an array? What do you mean "how can I import individual entires"? In that file, each word is mapped to a truthy value (in this case `1`). When using this file, you are meant to use it like so `if (dictionary[wordToTest]) { console.log(wordToTest + ' is a word!'); } else { console.log(wordToTest + ' is not a word!'); }`

Comment: @NicholasKeough What do you mean by "import things" ? Do you mean simply accessing individual key/value pairs in from the loaded JSON dictionary ?

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the data you're loading isn't a regular array (`[]`) with values accessed using an integer index, but a JavaScript `Object` or associative array(`{}`) with values accessed using a string instead of an integer index.

This is a key-value pair association.
Let's say you have a simple association:

```
let data = {
  "firstName": "Nicholas",
  "lastName":  "Keough",
}
```

In the example above `firstName` and `lastName` are keys and `"Nicholas"` and `"Keough"` are values.
You can use array like `[]` and instead of an integer index, you'd use the key:

```
console.log(data["firstName"]);// prints "Nicholas"
console.log(data["lastName"]);// prints "Keough"
```

alternatively you can use dot notation:

```
console.log(data.firstName);// prints "Nicholas"
console.log(data.lastName);// prints "Keough"
```

In your case, let's say `dictionary` is a variable that holds the loaded JSON data,
you apply the same ideas above to access each word. For example:

```
console.log(data['absorbent']);//prints 1
```

or

```
console.log(data.absorbent.);//prints 1
```

If you need to loop over the values (and in your case, with the dictionary of 370101 values, you would really want to), you can use a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Alternatively, if you simply need to access the keys, not the values, as a single array you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Here's a basic example illustrating both options:
(Bare in mind the dictionary is large so it will take time to load and print the data to console)

```js
let dictionary;
// preload JSON data
function preload(){
  dictionary = loadJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_dictionary.json");
}

function setup(){
  noLoop();
  console.log('test');  
  // access JSON data with a for...in loop
  for(let word in dictionary){
    console.log("word: " + word + " value: " + dictionary[word]);
  }
  
  // optionally, access the associative array keys only as an array
  console.log(Object.keys(dictionary));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```